# Add straight-line in ggplot with date on the x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have below ggplot.

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1)
dat = rbind(data.frame(y = rnorm(10, 10, 1), x = as.Date('2000-01-01')), data.frame(y = rnorm(10, 5, 1), x = as.Date('2000-02-01')), data.frame(y = rnorm(10, 15, 1), x = as.Date('2000-03-01')))

ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
geom_point(size = 3, alpha = 0.5)
```

Now I want to draw another straight-line which pass through 0 and having slope 1.

I tried adding `geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1)`, but it does not add any line

Is there any way to perform the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the $x$ axis consists of dates the origin of your coordinate system is Jan 1st 1970:

```r
as.Date('2000-01-01') - as.numeric(as.Date('2000-01-01'))
# "1970-01-01"
```

Thus ggplot actually adds the line to your plot, but it is not visible. A quick fix to deal with this is to specify in such a way that the line goes through your first date:

```r
ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point(size = 3, alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_abline(intercept = -as.numeric(as.Date('2000-01-01')), slope = 1)
```

Notice that this only works because `slope = 1` in this example. If you have a different slope you can achieve the same behaviour by

```r
slope = 5
ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point(size = 3, alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_abline(intercept = - slope * as.numeric(as.Date('2000-01-01')), slope = slope)
```

Comment: FYI, programming requests (without a meaningful statistical core) are off-topic on CV. They will likely be closed quickly, and it's more useful to flag them instead of answering.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that!

Comment: @mkt answering is more useful to OP

Comment: @rep_ho Yes, I know. I won't argue for why retaining a topic focus is useful, as I'm sure you recognise that given that you voted to close. I will say that answers to closed questions are less likely to attract upvotes and attention, which can be demotivating. So if a question is likely to be closed, I'd prefer to not have new members waste their time answering it.

Comment: @mkt it's definitely a SO question, but IMO writing an answer that solves someone problem might be motivating enough, so it is not a waste of time anymore then helping someone through an email or near a water-cooler.

Comment: @rep_ho I understand your position; this is occasionally debated on SE and yours may be closer to the median opinion (among experienced users) than mine: https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4528/answering-off-topic-questions-appropriate and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133552/should-i-answer-off-topic-questions .